# How I can write mathematical expression on EditText?

Tags: android, math, android-edittext

I'm new at this forum, this is my first post. So, I've created an app with custom keyboard that displays, mathematical characters , such as integrals, sinus, power ... .After that , I wanted to insert these characters on a EditText , that works fine , but the problem is I wanted to create a mathematical expression something like this https://ibb.co/F7j22BY.

***What I have tried:***
- I have tried Mathjax, which is for web and not for mobiles , so the only way is to show the expression on a webview, and it's not what I really wan't.

Comment: AFAIK You can not do this in `EditText` event with `Html.fromHtml()` . Math String follow some specific notation which then converted into readable Text using Java script . So I think Web View is the Only Option You got .

Comment: Try making custom edit text with custom allowed character set.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this library. https://github.com/jianzhongli/MathView

To add this library to your project, go to your build.gradle (module) and add:

```
implementation 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'
```

Then define `MathView` in XML Layout File

```
<LinearLayout ...>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Formula two: from Java String with KaTeX"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
    android:id="@+id/formula_two"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    auto:engine="KaTeX"
    >
</io.github.kexanie.library.MathView>
```

Then, configure it in your Code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MathView formula_two;
String tex = "This come from string. You can insert inline formula:" +
        " \\(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\\) " +
        "or displayed formula: $$\\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \\frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    formula_two = (MathView) findViewById(R.id.formula_two);
    formula_two.setText(tex);
    editText.setHint(formula_two.getText().toString());
 }
}
```

to set EditText hint just use `editText.setHint(formula_two.getText().toString)`
So you could make the MathView Invisible somewhere but retrieve its text

Answer (score 0):

**jqMath** is a JavaScript module that makes it easy to put formatted mathematical expressions in your activity.
you can download it online.
[download Jqmath from this link](https://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html)